# Python unittest, running only the tests that failed

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I have a large python test file using unittest that I run from the command line.  Some tests take a while to run. This is a mild pain point because I'm often only concerned with the last test I added. What I want is this:

1. add test.
2. run tests  (one fails because I haven't written the code to make it pass)
3. implement the behaviour
4. run only the test that failed last time
5. fix the silly error I made when implementing the code
6. run only the failing test, which passes this time
7. run all the tests to find out what I broke.

Is it possible to do this from the command line?

Comment: Breaking your unit tests into seperate files would solve your problems most likely.

Comment: How would that work? I still need python to know which files worked and which didn't...

Comment: Yes, but you need to create it yourself. You can import `unittest`, run discovery, collect the failed tests and then execute only those. But you'll have to create your own CLI.

Answer (score 1):

(Not a fully automated solution, but better than the existing one)

If you pass the name of a test class as an argument to the test script, only that test will be run. For example, if you only want to run tests in the `MyTest` class in the script `test_whatever.py`:

```
python3 test_whatever.py MyTest
```

You can also specify an individual test as a member of that class. For example, suppose you want to run the test `test_something` in the class `MyTest`:

```
python3 test_whatever.py MyTest.test_something
```

Comment: Upvoted because that gets me most of the way there - will leave open for the time being in case someone has a very handy thing we haven't seen yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Every test function is declared like:

```
    def test_something_something(self):
```

If you add an underscore in front, like:

```
    def _test_something_something(self):
```

that test will be ignored. One thing you can do is to do a quick [find and replace in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace). Find all "test_"s and replace them with "_test_" and then find the one test that failed and remove the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the test with **--last-failed** option (you might need pytest)

Comment: This is not an option!

Comment: @chiktin As per documentation https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html

The plugin provides two command line options to rerun failures from the last pytest invocation:

--lf, --last-failed - to only re-run the failures.
--ff, --failed-first - to run the failures first and then the rest of the tests.